# how to get focus on grid on arrow key down and want to give functionality of listbox on pressing arrow up or arrow down

Tags: java, gwt, grid

i am making searching module i want to make focus on grid on key up handler of textbox when clicking on arrow up key or arrow down key then it get focus on grid and working as listbox on pressing arrow key up or arrow key down....and get value of particular row on double click event of that row..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;  
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyDownEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyDownHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;
import com.gwtext.client.core.EventObject;  
import com.gwtext.client.data.*;  
import com.gwtext.client.widgets.Panel;  
import com.gwtext.client.widgets.grid.ColumnConfig;  
import com.gwtext.client.widgets.grid.ColumnModel;  
import com.gwtext.client.widgets.grid.GridPanel;  

public class imagegrid1 implements EntryPoint 
{  
TextBox textbox=new TextBox();
Label l = new Label("search");
Panel panel = new Panel();  
VerticalPanel vp=new VerticalPanel();
Label label=new Label();

GridPanel grid = new GridPanel();  

String name="";
int i=1;

private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

public void onModuleLoad() 
{  
    textbox.addKeyUpHandler(new AlphaKeyPress());
    textbox.setPixelSize(250, 30);

    RootPanel.get().add(l);
    RootPanel.get().add(textbox);
    RootPanel.get().add(vp);
}  
public class AlphaKeyPress implements KeyUpHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
    {
        String ab =textbox.getText();
```

//          Window.alert(""+ab.length());

```
        if(ab.length()>0 && !(event.isDownArrow()||event.isUpArrow()))
        {
            greetingService.server(ab,new AsyncCallback<String>()
            {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
                    {
                        Window.alert("Invalid");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) 
                    { 
                        System.out.println("At the client side..."+result);
                        vp.clear();




                        if(result.isEmpty())
                        { 
                            label.setText("not found");
                            vp.add(label);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vp.clear();
                            String match=textbox.getText();


                            panel.setPixelSize(260, 90);
```

//                              panel.setBorder(false);

```
                            RecordDef recordDef = new RecordDef
                            (  
                                    new FieldDef[]
                                    {  
                                        new StringFieldDef("company"),  

                                    }  
                            );  

                            Object[][] data = getCompanyData(result); 
                            MemoryProxy proxy = new MemoryProxy(data); 
                            ArrayReader reader = new ArrayReader(recordDef); 
                            Store store = new Store(proxy, reader);  
                            ColumnConfig[] columns = new ColumnConfig[]
                                                                {  

                                                                        new ColumnConfig("", "company", 300, true, null, "company"),  

                                                                };  
                            ColumnModel columnModel = new ColumnModel(columns);

                            System.out.println("datalength="+data.length);



                            System.out.println("GETCOMPANYDATA=+"+getCompanyData(result));



                            System.out.println("proxyyyy="+proxy.toString());




                            if(i==1)
                            {
                                store.load();  
                                grid.setStore(store);  
                                grid.setColumnModel(columnModel);
                                i++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                store.load();
                                grid.reconfigure(store, columnModel);
                            }





                            grid.setHeight(90);  
                            grid.setWidth(258);  



                          panel.add(grid); 
                          vp.add(panel);




                        }

                    }
                });
        }

    }
}

private Object[][] getCompanyData(String result) 
{ 
    ArrayList <String> al;
    al=new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] temp = null;

    System.out.println("object data"+result);

    for (String retval: result.split("/"))
    {
        System.out.println(retval);
        al.add(retval);
    }
    int siz=al.size();
    System.out.println(siz);
    temp = new String[siz];
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = al.get(i);

    }


    String[][] kk = new String[temp.length][1];
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    {
        kk[i][0]=temp[i];
        System.out.println("temp data"+kk[i][0]);

    }
    return kk;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd want to use `SuggestBox` with a custom `SuggestionDisplay` (one that wraps your `VerticalPanel` and displays data in a `GridPanel`, rather than the default popup-menu behavior)

Comment: no no its not that,,i need to fetch the data from the database,,if u have any suggestion regarding to my problem then pls reply

Comment: And? `SuggestBox` can very-well fetch suggestions from your server: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/gwt/widgetideas/client/RPCSuggestOracle.java